# user notification implementation using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I am trying to implement a user notification service.

Problem statement:
User will be able to set a reminder for a particular DateTime.
At that particular time my app should send user a notification via SMS or email.

Technologies using:
Spring Boot, Spring-Scheduler, Spring-Batch

Problem Facing:
Wanted to run the instance of this app on 4 different machines.
But I am afraid that user will get duplicate notifications.

How should I solve this problem preferably using these technologies?
Does Spring-Batch provide some mechanism to handle this issue?
Does Spring-Batch's JobRepository could solve this problem. If yes how?(please provide code snippet).

Comment: I'm not sure you need Spring Batch for this use case. What do you want to batch process here?

Comment: Will this functionality - **User will be able to set a reminder for a particular DateTime** be also part of this system or DateTime be already available to this system & this system's job is to only notify?